# what is ComboBox message 359 0x167?

Tags: winapi, combobox, controls, message

I cannot find this info anywhere, including in the official Windows API documentation. It is sent to the subclassing procedure when the control loses focus. It is not defined in winuser.h.

It is sent like this:

```
0x02D - WM_DELETEITEM
0x167 - ???
0x202 - WM_LBUTTONUP
```

My compiler is MinGW, system Windows XP SP3.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having where you think this message will solve it?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm just curious as for now. Until now I was able to found every message I encountered and I'm surprised that there are message that are not documented.

Comment: Then this is not a practical question if your only reason for asking is curiosity. StackOverflow is for practical questions.

Comment: If you're subclassing a window, it could be helpful to know what messages are passing through so you can be sure to handle the correctly.  Without knowing, all you can do is pass them to the original wndproc and hope it does the right thing in the context of whatever it is your subclass does.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, these things are poorly documented by Microsoft and you never know when a future reader may need to know them. If a question about Windows API programming is off-topic on SO, I don't know what's on-topic.

Comment: This is not "poorly documented", it is **undocumented**.  Quite intentional.

Comment: @HansPassant: It is poorly documented. The fact that given message is for system use only should be clearly stated (since it is exposed to user written subclassing function) and not implied by simple absence of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0x167` is in the range of messages that is reserved for system use.  Messages in this range that are not explicitly defined in the SDK are private for the system's internal use.  This is stated as much in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931.aspx):

> #define WM_USER 0x0400

.

> 0 through WM_USER –1
>
> Messages reserved for use by the system.
>
> Message numbers in the first range (0 through WM_USER –1) are defined by the system. Values in this range **that are not explicitly defined** are reserved by the system.

Comment: All true, but it doesn't answer the question.  WM_PAINT (0x000F) is in this range too, but that one is documented and easy to find in winuser.h

Comment: There are many undocumented messages reserved for the system. This appears to be one of them.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Read the part of the documentation that I highlighted more carefully. `WM_PAINT` is in the same range, but it is an explicitly defined message and thus documented. 0x167 is not explicitly defined, so it is private and undocumented. That answers the OP's question about where it is documented - it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Fine, I retract my comment.  I think we have different interpretations of what was being asked.

Answer (score -1):

The 0x167 message respond for selecting text in combo edit control